# With Node Js, Socket.Io bot making

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

How to run javascript with node js without opening google chrome from different proxies.
Can i get a sample code.

eg project: https://github.com/huytd/agar.io-clone
eg2project: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19v9lxRrRqrMp6n3k5rbDRljGVdLYELQc?usp=sharing

I don't want to use the project i link to

briefly: I'm trying to find a code that goes to Facebook.com/nick and clicks the send message button

Comment: Hi ! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The way your question is written does not really express what you are looking for. You are also lacking a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have already done.

Comment: Just enter on the project folder and type the follow command:

node yourfile.js

That's it.

Comment: I don't want to use the project i link to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puppeteer: puppeteer is no-gui-on-gui chromium browser. and nodejs